# How do you put the enchantments "Fortify Alchemy" or "Fortify Enchanting" on armour?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Call me ignorant, but I can't figure this one out. I've got a "Fortify Alchemy" enchantment, and I cannot put it on armour. Is there a certain type of armour I could put it on?

Answer (score 10):

You cannot put fortify enchantment onto armor as that would create a feedback loop, and this was intentionally taken out.  Likewise, you cannot make a fortify alchemy potion.

However, you CAN put fortify alchemy onto these pieces of armor:

- helmets and circlets
- necklaces
- rings
- gloves

To do so, just find a piece of gear with the fortify alchemy enchantment on it, and then disenchant it (looks like you have already done this step).  From then on, you can now use that enchantment on the previously mentioned gear.

There is a pretty well known trick that you can wear both a Falmer helmet and a circlet at the same time, so in actuality you can get up to 5 pieces of armor with the fortify alchemy bonus.

There is a pretty good [table](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects) on uesp that shows you what enchantments can go onto what armor.

Comment: You can craft *potions* of fortify enchanting, so they didn't actually break the feedback loop, they just made it moderately harder to execute. This exploit is usually combined with the [fortify restoration glitch](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Glitches#Infinitely_Powerful_Items).

Comment: @Kevin, the feedback loop between potions of fortify enchanting and armor of fortify alchemy has diminishing returns, converging to a maximum of +38%, +44%, +61%, +114%, or +127% enchanting, depending on your version of the game and what patches and DLCs you have installed.

Comment: @Mark: Not when you combine it with Fortify Restoration, as described in the linked article.